# Is it possible to condense long code using an array or collection?

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

I've got this code here that I've written to nest several if/then/else statements within each other. It works for what I need it to; it complies and runs as expected, but it's *really long* and this is only roughly 1/12th of what it'll end up being. It's way too big to manage, so I'm hoping there might be a way to condense it somehow.

```
package randomlist;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
    
public class Randomlist {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Random generate = new Random();
           String[] name = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};           
           String nesting =(name[generate.nextInt(4)]);
           
           if ("A".equals(nesting)) {
               System.out.println("A");
               Random generate1 = new Random();
               String[] name1 = {"R", "E", "M"};           
               String nesting1 =(name1[generate1.nextInt(3)]);
               Thread.sleep(1000);
               if ("R".equals(nesting1)) {
                   System.out.println("R"); }
               else
                   if ("E".equals(nesting1)) {
                   System.out.println("E");}
                   else
                   if ("M".equals(nesting1)) {
                       System.out.println("M");}}
           if ("B".equals(nesting)) {
               System.out.println("B");
               Random generate1 = new Random();
               String[] name1 = {"R", "E", "M"};           
               String nesting1 =(name1[generate1.nextInt(3)]);
               Thread.sleep(1000);
               if ("R".equals(nesting1)) {
                   System.out.println("R"); }
               else
                   if ("E".equals(nesting1)) {
                   System.out.println("E");}
                   else
                   if ("M".equals(nesting1)) {
                       System.out.println("M");}}
           if ("C".equals(nesting)) {
               System.out.println("C");
               Random generate1 = new Random();
               String[] name1 = {{"R", "E", "M"};          
               String nesting1 =(name1[generate1.nextInt(3)]);
               Thread.sleep(1000);
               if ("R".equals(nesting1)) {
                   System.out.println("R"); }
               else
                   if ("E".equals(nesting1)) {
                   System.out.println("E");}
                   else
                   if ("M".equals(nesting1)) {
                       System.out.println("M");}}
           if ("D".equals(nesting)) {
               System.out.println("D");
               Random generate1 = new Random();
               String[] name1 = {{"R", "E", "M"};          
               String nesting1 =(name1[generate1.nextInt(3)]);
               Thread.sleep(1000);
               if ("R".equals(nesting1)) {
                   System.out.println("R"); }
               else
                   if ("E".equals(nesting1)) {
                   System.out.println("E");}
                   else
                   if ("M".equals(nesting1)) {
                       System.out.println("M");}}
           }}
```

Comment: Use your IDE refactoring feature. Identical blocks can be extracted to their own function and reused elsewhere.  Since nesting always contains either A, B, C, or D and pretty much then just gets printed as is, you can snip that too, unless you have a different logic, in which case generalize them so the common part are called as a function.

Comment: Your various cases look identical. Just what is special about A, B, or C? When posting here, put more effort into making your Question crystal-clear.

Comment: I intentionally cut it down so no one would start picking apart the details, as tends to happen. I provided just enough information for people to be able to give an answer, which someone did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your branches all do the same thing. Print the `String nesting` wait a second and then print the `String nesting1` which you pick in the same manner. Your code could be simplified to

```
Random generate = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
String[] name = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
String[] name1 = { "R", "E", "M" };
String nesting = name[generate.nextInt(name.length)];
String nesting1 = name1[generate.nextInt(name1.length)];
System.out.println(nesting);
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println(nesting1);
```

Of course, that uses a tiny bit of repetitious code; we could extract that into a method to pick a random element from an array. Perhaps a generic method, that for some type `T` takes an array of type `T` and returns a `T`. Something like,

```
static <T> T randomElement(T[] arr) {
    return arr[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(arr.length)];
}
```

Then the code becomes

```
String[] name = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
String[] name1 = { "R", "E", "M" };
System.out.println(randomElement(name));
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println(randomElement(name1));
```

Which is about as simple as I can imagine.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly and is going to save me so much time and space. I knew my code wasn't "too confusing" as the other commenters said. I intentionally cut it down to bare-bones so it wouldn't potentially confuse anyone with superfluous details.

Comment: Your updated code doesn't work; it throws unhandled exceptions because "cbuf is null" and points to line 214. The first code you gave works perfectly fine and saves me from 48 copy-pastes; it allows me to simply fill in the rest of the random items and then add one more nested variable in "name2".

Comment: Posted code includes nothing called `cbuf`. I've tested all the code in my answer. Feel free to use whichever works best for you.

Comment: I know it doesn't. But the error is "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "cbuf" is null
 at java.base/java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:213)
 at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.writeln(PrintStream.java:677)
 at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:1010)
 at randomlist.Randomlist.main(Randomlist.java:12)". It's not an error in the code, it's an error when it executes. It compiles with no errors, but it won't run.

Comment: Runs [fine here](https://i.imgur.com/wzuCklF.png). Would need more context to help.

Comment: I don't have more context; I copy-pasted the code over the other code, told it to create the method "randomElement(String[])" since it was undefined for the type Randomlist, and told it to compile. It did so without any warnings. When executed, it gives that error.

Comment: Did you try using the method `randomElement` I posted, instead of generating a new one. Please see [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/wzuCklF.png).